# Double linear sequence gives odd results

Tags: c#, performance, sequence, formula

I'm trying to get my performance skills (none existent) up to par but ran into a problem with writing out a formula into code. This is the formula I'm trying to - quote unquote - "convert" to code.

> Consider a sequence u where u is defined as follows:
>
> The number `u(0) = 1` is the first one in `u`.
>   For each `x` in `u`, then `y = 2 * x + 1` and `z = 3 * x + 1` must be in `u` too.
>   There are no other numbers in `u`.
>   Ex: `u = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19, 21, 22, 27, ...]`
>
> `1` gives `3` and `4`, then `3` gives `7` and `10`, `4` gives `9` and `13`, then `7` gives `15` and `22` and so on...

And this is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DblLinear(10));
        //Expected result: 22
        Console.WriteLine(DblLinear(20));
        //Expected result: 57
        Console.WriteLine(DblLinear(30));
        //Expected result: 91
        Console.WriteLine(DblLinear(50));
        //Expected result: 175
    }
    public static int DblLinear (int n) 
    {
        List<int> linArr = new List<int>();
        linArr.Add(1);

        int i = 0;
        while(linArr.Count < n)
        {
            linArr.Add((2 * linArr[i]) + 1);
            linArr.Add((3 * linArr[i]) + 1);
            linArr.Sort();
            i++;
        }
        return linArr[n - 1];
    }
}
```

The calculations are right until it hits 27. After that it just runs wild and I have no idea what it does wrong.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with the debugger?

Comment: You are not checking if the number already exists, before adding it. You'll have duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You take one item from sequence and produce two. So You really need some data structure to store them, as their numbers would increase. Heap would be the best. If You want to go with what we have directly in .net, You can use `SortedSet`.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> DblLinear2()
{
    SortedSet<int> seq = new SortedSet<int> { 1 };

    while (true)
    {
        int min = seq.First();
        seq.Remove(min);
        yield return min;
        seq.Add(min * 2 + 1);
        seq.Add(min * 3 + 1);
    }
}
```

The result:

> 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19, 21, 22, 27, 28, 31, 39, 40, 43, 45, 46,
>   55, 57, 58, 63, 64, 67, 79, 81, 82, 85, 87...

Comment: This is perfect. A simple `ElementAt()` call and it returns any value I throw at it. Added to that that there's no worries about none null-based returns either, this has to be the answer that does it all. Also never knew `SortedSet<T>` existed. Definitely have to look that one up.

Answer (score 2):

What's going wrong is that you're using a single index to build your values.

When you get to `i == 27`, as per your example, the first series produces `55` and the second produces `82`. But the first should have also produced `57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81` before the second produces `82` for your sequence to be properly computed.

You need to run two separate indexes and only increment each when the value produced by their respective series is lowest (or equal to the other).

Here's how I would do it:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> DblLinear()
{
    Func<int, int> fxy = x => 2 * x + 1;
    Func<int, int> fxz = x => 3 * x + 1;

    var intermediate = new System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet<int>();

    Action<int> safeAdd = x =>
    {
        if (!intermediate.Contains(x))
        {
            intermediate.Add(x);
        }
    };

    safeAdd(1);

    while (true)
    {
        var x = intermediate.First();
        safeAdd(fxy(x));
        safeAdd(fxz(x));
        intermediate.Remove(x);
        yield return x;
    }
}
```

Now this can be used to produce the entire sequence so it is a good idea to use the LINQ `.Take(...)` operator.

You could using it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", DblLinear().Take(20)));
```

...and that gives me:

> 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19, 21, 22, 27, 28, 31, 39, 40, 43, 45, 46, 55

Your test code, once modified to handle the list, works just fine:

```
    Console.WriteLine(DblLinear().Skip(10).First());
    //Expected result: 22
    Console.WriteLine(DblLinear().Skip(20).First());
    //Expected result: 57
    Console.WriteLine(DblLinear().Skip(30).First());
    //Expected result: 91
    Console.WriteLine(DblLinear().Skip(50).First());
    //Expected result: 175
```

Comment: Ahh... This leads em to believe that I simply hadn't let the while loop run long enough to garner the correct values at the requested indexes. I see, I see.

Comment: @sxbrentxs - Perhaps, but you need to run it to the point that the first sequence has produced enough values and then you need to remove duplicates and truncate your list before returning a value. Using my approach would be far more efficient.

Comment: The `yi++` approach is wrong, You should get output of the function as a next source, not simple 1, 2, 3,... sequence

Comment: Yeah, @AntonínLejsek, I tried using the `ElementAt()`, but that returns too low a value. I.e. `DblLinear().ElementAt(10)` is desired to return 22, but returns 16 (Now is `ElementAt()` null-based, so a `ElementAt(n-1)` would be needed, but.. potato, potato.). Converting to a sequence (`IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`) gives the same results, figures, as `ElementAt()` might as well be a one on one wrapper for the same code/idea. But you say the `yi++;` approach is wrong. What's incorrect about it? You mean it's calculating the values "too quickly" (index 10 = 16 instead of 22)?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek - I don't understand what you're saying. Can you please explain your comment a little more?

Comment: @sxbrentxs - Can you explain what I'm doing wrong? I thought I implemented the algorithm correctly. If it's not producing the right value I must have gotten something wrong or there's something missing from the explanation in the question.

Comment: The `yi++` produces sequence 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,... and from that You calculate `2*x+1` => 1, 3, 5, 7, 9,... But this does not correspond to the task. The formula says - if there is some number `n` in the sequence, then there is also `2*n+1` and `3*n+1` in the sequence. And there are no other numbers. For example 5 should not be in the result, because 2 is not there either.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Well. There you go: ^

Comment: @AntonínLejsek - Ah, I think I see. Only members of the set `u` can define future members by the two functions. Sounds like a job for a priority queue.

Comment: @sxbrentxs - I've fixed my solution. It works as expected now.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek - I updated my answer before seeing yours. We've basically come up with the same approach. I should have realised that I didn't need the `safeAdd` though.