# What data structure would be best for this in Java and how could I implement it efficiently?

Tags: java, algorithm

This is for a coding challenge on codewars. Conditions of the challenge: 
Consider a sequence u where u is defined as follows:

```
The number u(0) = 1 is the first one in u.
For each x in u, then y = 2 * x + 1 and z = 3 * x + 1 must be in u too.
There are no other numbers in u.
Ex: u = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19, 21, 22, 27, ...]

1 gives 3 and 4, then 3 gives 7 and 10, 4 gives 9 and 13, then 7 gives 15 and 22 and so on...

Task:
Given parameter n the function dbl_linear (or dblLinear...) returns the element u(n) of the ordered (with <) sequence u (so, there are no duplicates).
```

My naive implementation that just generates 250000 numbers:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

class DoubleLinear {
        private static Set<Integer> nums;
        private static Set<Integer> seen;

        public static int dblLinear (int n) {
                nums = new TreeSet<>();
                seen = new HashSet<>();
                nums.add(1);
                for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
                        generateNumbers();
                }
                List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList(nums);
                return numList.get(n);
        }

        public static void generateNumbers () {
                for (int x : new TreeSet<Integer>(nums)) {
                        if (seen.contains(x)) continue;
                        if (nums.size() >= 250000) break; 
                        int y = (2*x) + 1, z = (3*x) + 1;
                        if (y > 0) nums.add(y);
                        if (z > 0) nums.add(z);
                        seen.add(x);
                }
        }
}
```

I'm curious what other structures I could use to increase efficiency here, because I am clearly missing the knowledge necessary to solve this.

Comment: How about `boolean[10000000]`?

Comment: Your question title is horrible.
But just by reading it, it seems like your question would be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You don't need to generate all of them at the start.  Consider you're given n=10 (so looking to return 21), then by the time you're counting through 15 or so, you've no interest in the lower numbers like 3 or 4 - they've served their purpose and can be forgotten.  So I'd keep a running list of "relevant" numbers as you're progressing, and let them drop off the end when they're no longer required.

Comment: @racraman yeah that makes great sense to me but i just wasn't sure which numbers i could safely forget about while still getting an accurate count

Comment: look at the formulas - the highest multiple is 3*x + 1.  So for each number, you can drop those where the value of x is below that.  eg. if you're looking at 15, you can discard numbers below (15 - 1)/3 = 4.6666, so discard 4 or below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like "double linear sequence" is a known thing. You may want to look into the first response to this question:

[Double linear sequence gives odd results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516045/double-linear-sequence-gives-odd-results)

The code is in C#, and uses a **SortedSet** (which is available in Java as well, I believe), and uses Lazy Evaluation with `IEnumerable` and `yield return`, which I think can be done with Java (https://codurance.com/2018/11/26/the-functional-style-part-7/)

Comment: wow i feel really dumb now, that solution was right in front of me haha. between that and racraman's comment i figured it out. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can store your numbers in HashMap to store the number.
Using x as the key and (Y or Z) as the  value.